# batch file - check if job was done previously and decide to do the job or not

Tags: batch-file

I have made a Batch file to create a folder from filename, then copy the file into the newly created folder.

```
for /F "Tokens=*" %%i in ('Dir /B *.mp4') do md "%%~ni"|copy "%%i" "%%~ni"
```

Now I need an "extension" that it is checked, if a folder was previously created or not. 
IF it was created, then stop and jump to the next.
If NOT, created like above.

The newly created folders will be moved afterwards so they dont exist for long.

Comment: Why `md` command pipes to `copy`?

Comment: What about switch `/V` of the `copy` command? it verifies whether the copying was successful (by trying to read it, I think); this implies that the directory has been created successfully...

Comment: @npocmaka, I guess the OP meant `&` rather than `|`...

Comment: @aschipfl where should I write the /V and what should it do? It does not create some kind of log/history i assume?

Comment: Type `copy /?` in a command prompt window and read the help, so you will see where to put it; this does not output any log, it just checks whether the destination file exists (it does not do a comparison with the source, it just attempty to read it and perhaps it checks the file size; if not successful, `copy` should set the `ErrorLevel`)...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for /F "Tokens=*" %%i in ('Dir /B *.mp4') do IF NOT EXIST "%%~ni" md "%%~ni" | copy "%%i" "%%~ni"
```

Comment: that would only solve half the problem. As I said, the newly created folder will be moved (but the source will stay for a while), a new folder will be created if the script runs again. there has to be somethink like
`check file oldnames.txt if filename exists, stop, if not, proceed for /F "Tokens......` and in the end `write foldername in oldnames.txt`

Comment: Sorry give me a few mins and I'll write the rest for you just heading home! Got ahead of myself on that one apologies

Comment: No problem mate! 
Is it possible to do this for only some folders? lets say only folder "c:\abc" but not for "c:\123"? I would likt to call this bat after torrents are finished but only for some special torrents

Comment: Well I was thinking of creating an exclude file and writing to that once created, but if you are thinking for torrents would it be any chance for renaming movies then moving them to the correct directory by any chance?

Comment: If the torrent is renamed, I cant seed them anymore.

Comment: If the directory is changed you can't either, I'd probably abandon the script if this is a utorrent thing you want to accomplish and see if it's possible to use the runprogram feature of utorrent to create your folders and such, but if you are looking for something to rename move and sort I have found something amazing, I use it for my movies and to shows to rename, move, download artwork and such then send a notification to plex to update, it's called filebot and then there's a custom script called amc.groovy (which may actually have the parameters to do what you want)

Comment: I do only rename/move the new files, not the sources. the sources will be seeded untill i decide to stop. 
Im not "moving" I copy the torrent. I want to use it as "run program" as you suggested :)

Comment: Right okay in that the scrip does have a copy function instead of move if that's of use?

Comment: So it will create a new folder in the location that you specify with an exclude list and copy the downloaded files rather than move so that way you can continue seeding as you wish

Comment: Here is what I was thinking: Torrents are stored in C\123, c:\ABC. Unfortunally I cant use the bat to only special folders, so I have to use it for all. But I only want it to run at C:\ABC. If a Torrent finishes in C:\123, the script should do nothing. So. C:\ABC\Blah1.mkv will be copied to C:\ABD\Blah1\Blah1.mkv. If I delete C:\ABD\Blah1\Blah1.mkv, the script should remember that it previously created a folder "Blah1" and skips to the next task

Comment: With the different folder names is it always going to be numbers? What is your identifying factor for the 2 types of folder, it has to have some kind of constant difference

Comment: It will be torrent names, Names and Numbers.
One will be for example TV Shows, The other will be sports, the other Movies, Full Bluray etc

Comment: So that's a problem you see, no 2 torrents are going to be the same so we have no way of telling the script to run only on certain files, what is the reason for running only on certain folders anyway?

Comment: Thats why I wanted to exclude some folders. Or like just "touch" them. Movie torrents for example dont need to be renamed, tv show torrents need renaming.

Comment: Right okay I think I'm with you, the only problem with that is you realise each time you will have to manually add folders that you want excluding to the exclude file as it won't know otherwise, but before we go ahead I want you to take a look at the following link and see if it has anything you can work with, you'd install the filebot that I mentioned earlier then use the script in conjunction. https://www.filebot.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=215

Comment: I wont "manually" add any folder. More or less its useable for me. It can only handle one folder as far as I can see.

Comment: It will run on everything in an existing directory if you set it the way I have, set utorrent to download to a specific folder then move to another once completed, save the command in a batch file rather than running it directly in utorrent which will then run once a torrent is completed on everything in that folder, anything it has already processed will be added to an exclude list, I can explain further, let's pick this up tomorrow and I'll go through it in more detail, comment tomorrow after 10am to remind me

Comment: right first start by reading this whole forum post   https://www.filebot.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=215

Comment: Well, I saw that and I answered to this yesterday. 
But thanks.

Comment: If you're adamant on not using that then at some point today i will write your batch file for you

Comment: that would be nice! :)